# GAE datastore admin page is blank

Tags: google-app-engine, datastore-admin

I have an app in GAE and since ever the DataStore Admin link, on the left, gives me a blank page. I noticed this is a bug because when checking, recently, DataStore Admin link, for another app, it properly shows a web page.

Expected: After enabling Data store admin link, over in Applications Settings, to actually have Datastore Admin page working. I tried to contact Google but they request me to be a Silver account — this is clearly a bug. I can upload a video if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and I fixed it by re-enabling third party cookies.  You might try clearing cache and cookies and trying another browser as well.